# $payment->users()->delete() didn't run deleted func in PaymentUserObserver in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a payment that it has many users I want to run deleted function in observer after deleting each user but the function didn't call!
users are payment's pivot table.

**Payment Observer deleting function**

`$payment->users()->delete();`

**PaymentUser observer deleted function**

`dd($paymentUser);`

**it didn't work with this code too**

`$payment->users()->get()->each->delete()`

Comment: Thank you for your question. However, the code you shared shows quite little about your logic as such. Please consider to share more than one line each so we can get a better idea of the surrounding code and how it might affect the result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Migration:** `$table->unsignedInteger('example')->primary()` **Or** `$table->id();`

**Model:** `protected $primaryKey = "example";`

**Code To Run Observer Method:** `$payment->users()->get()->each->delete();`

It Run Delete for Users One By One & It Trigger The Observer Deleted & Deleting Function.

Answer (score 1):

`$payment->users()->delete()` doesn't pass thru the observers because it runs a SQL delete. It should be:

```
$payment->users()->get()->each->delete();
```